# Reshape data long data in R or aggregate?

Tags: r, reshape, dplyr

I have a data set that is in a long format, and I can’t seem to get it the right shape for analysis.  Perhaps this shape is appropriate — my experience has been almost entirely with wide format data, so this data file is not making sense to me. (Reproducible data file at end of the post.)

```
> head(df,10)
    ID attributes values
1   1         AU    AAA
2   1         AU    BBB
3   1         YR   2014
4   2         AU    CCC
5   2         AU    DDD
6   2         AU    EEE
7   2         AU    FFF
8   2         AU    GGG
9   2         YR   2013
10  3         AU    HHH
```

The attributes column contain variables of interest to me, and I want to perform a series of aggregation functions.  For example, I would like to:

1.Obtain a count of the number of authors (AU) for each ID.  For example:

```
   ID       N.AU
    1           2
    2           5
    3           1
    4           2
    5           5
    6           1
```

2. Compute the median number of authors (AU) by year (YR)

   ```
   YR           Median.N.AU   
   2013          5.0
   2014          1.5
   ```

For both of these examples, I have tried dplry with group_by and summaries, but haven’t cracked the code.  I have also tried dcast.  My hope is to come up with a solution that I can easily generalize to a larger data frame that has many more attributes that take on either a single value or multiple values.  Any help or pointers to a similar solution would be greatly appreciated.

```
attributes = c("AU", "AU", "YR", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "YR", "AU", "YR",
   "AU", "AU", "YR", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "AU", "YR", "AU", "YR")
ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6)
values = c("AAA", "BBB", "2014", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF", "GGG", "2013", "HHH", "2014",
   "III", "JJJ", "2014", "KKK", "LLL", "MMM", "NNN", "OOO", "2013", "PPP", "2014")
df <- data.frame(ID, attributes, values)
```

Comment: A base solution for (1) could look like `aggregate(attributes ~ ID, data = df[df$attributes == "AU", ], FUN = length)`, a dplyr version could look like `df %>% filter(attributes == "AU") %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(N.AU = length(attributes))`. The column `YR` seems to be missing (?).

Comment: @lukeA I almost had the code right with the dplyr version, so thanks much!  The `YR` is what I am struggling with.  That is in the data file as a variable within the column, and that is what is giving me the problem!

Comment: Not sure why this question is receiving several down votes ?

Comment: That is what I was wondering!  I will try to improve my question with feedback ...The assistance I have received thus far has been very helpful for my particular need.

Comment: I think your median calculation is wrong

Comment: @DavidArenburg - yes, the calculation was wrong ... and now fixed. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're getting confused because you actually have two tables of
data linked by a common ID:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- tbl_df(df)

years <- df %>% 
  filter(attributes == "YR") %>% 
  select(id = ID, year = values)
years
#> Source: local data frame [6 x 2]
#> 
#>    id year
#> 1   1 2014
#> 2   2 2013
#> 3   3 2014
#> 4   4 2014
#> 5   5 2013
#> .. ..  ...

authors <- df %>% 
  filter(attributes == "AU") %>% 
  select(id = ID, author = values)
authors
#> Source: local data frame [16 x 2]
#> 
#>    id author
#> 1   1    AAA
#> 2   1    BBB
#> 3   2    CCC
#> 4   2    DDD
#> 5   2    EEE
#> .. ..    ...
```

Once you have the data in this form, it's easy to answer the questions
you're interested in:

1. Authors per paper:

   ```
   n_authors <- authors %>% 
     group_by(id) %>% 
     summarise(n = n())
   ```

   Or

   ```
   n_authors <- authors %>% count(id)
   ```
2. Median authors per year:

   ```
   n_authors %>%
     left_join(years) %>%
     group_by(year) %>%
     summarise(median(n))
   #> Joining by: "id"
   #> Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
   #> 
   #>   year median(n)
   #> 1 2013       5.0
   #> 2 2014       1.5
   ```

Comment: @docendodiscimus yup, just added an example

Comment: Yes, the two tables with the common ID is a better description of my confusion. I will certainly edit the title of the post if that would be better.  Thx much!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possible `data.table` solution

I would also suggest to create some aggregated data set with separated columns. For example:

```
library(data.table)
(subdf <- as.data.table(df)[, .(N.AU = sum(attributes == "AU"),
                                Year = values[attributes == "YR"]) , ID])
#    ID N.AU Year
# 1:  1    2 2014
# 2:  2    5 2013
# 3:  3    1 2014
# 4:  4    2 2014
# 5:  5    5 2013
# 6:  6    1 2014
```

Calculating median per year

```
subdf[, .(Median.N.AU = median(N.AU)), keyby = Year]
#    Year Median.N.AU
# 1: 2013         5.0
# 2: 2014         1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I misunderstood the structure of your dataset initially.  Thanks to the comments below I realize your data needs to be restructured.

```
# split the data out
df1 <- df[df$attributes == "AU",]
df2 <- df[df$attributes == "YR",]

# just keeping the columns with data as opposed to the label
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="ID")[,c(1,3,5)]
# set column names for clarification
colnames(df3) <- c("ID","author","year")

# get author counts
num.authors <- count(df3, vars=c("ID","year"))
  ID year freq
1  1 2014    2
2  2 2013    5
3  3 2014    1
4  4 2014    2
5  5 2013    5
6  6 2014    1

summaryBy(freq ~ year, data = num.authors, FUN = list(median))
  year freq.median
1 2013         5.0
2 2014         1.5
```

The nice thing about `summaryBy` is that you can add in which ever function has been defined in the list and you will get another column containing the other metric (e.g. mean, sd, etc.)

Comment: Avoid `which` in both examples. It works, but is not required and not Rish.

Comment: @DieterMenne, removing `which` does work but doesn't provide the filtered output the OP displayed.  Was there an alternative that you recommend?

Comment: I do not see a difference when I use `count(df[df$attributes == "AU",], vars=c("ID", "attributes"))`. Did I miss something?

Comment: @DieterMenne, AH!, I misunderstood, I thought you were saying to remove the filters.  You are indeed correct that `which` is not needed.  Thank you

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thank you, I embarrassingly overlooked the structure of the dataset.  I have edited my answer accordingly.